# how can you put samples together and make a drum machine out of them for midi instruments?

Tags: drums, garage-band, drum-machine

how can you add samples together in garageband to make a drum set on a midi? I want to group my samples of 1 beat drums into an instrument so I can play the midi like a drum machine. Lmk

Answer (score 1):

That feature is available on the EXS24 sample editor in Logic Pro but I’m almost certain you can’t do it in GarageBand. GarageBand does have many pre programmed drum kits though.